# Custom UserConfirmation not being called in Asp.Net Core 5 Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-5.0

Using Asp.Net Core 5.0 I am adding Identity and a custom UserConfirmation:

```
  services
    .AddIdentityCore<User>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<Context>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddUserConfirmation<UserConfirmation<User>>();
```

Where my custom `UserConfirmation` is the following:

```
  public class UserConfirmation<T> : IUserConfirmation<T> where T : User {

    public async virtual Task<Boolean> IsConfirmedAsync(UserManager<T> manager, T user) {
      
      if (!user.Enabled)
        return false;

      if (!await manager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user)) 
        return false;
      
      return true;

    }

  }
```

However the method `CanSignInAsync`:

```
_signInManager.CanSignInAsync(user)
```

returns always `true` even with user is not enabled.

And the breakpoint I added in `IsConfirmedAsync` is not being triggered.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem. The following needs to be added to Identity options:

```
services.AddIdentityCore<User>(options => {
  options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
})
```